# Setting focus on an element that is displayed after a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accessibility

I'm trying to get an accessibility effect on a slider I'm adding to my site. Basically what I want to do is, when you click (press enter) on the first slide , you get the focus on the second slide  element so you can continue tabbing through the page.
I'm using jquery and cycle plugin.

The problem is : when you click on the first element, the second element is still considered in display:none by js, so it can't reach it. Any idea how I might do this ? I think it should be simple enough, but I tried several possibilites and didnt succeed.

Here is my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/toplefty/nk4bgsfx/
and what I tried :

```
$('#s1').cycle({ 
    fx:     'slideY', 
    speed:  300, 
    next:   '#s1', 
    timeout: 0 
});


$('#Goto2').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('#s1').find('#Goto1').focus();
});
```

cycle options : http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

Comment: Is this what you want you want to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/gy8p5ewv/1/

Comment: excellent, thanks thats the wanted effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `after` property takes a function that is executed after the transition happens.

From the documentation for `after`:

> // transition callback (scope set to element that was shown): 
>   function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag)

So you can set the focus in there. http://jsfiddle.net/gy8p5ewv/1/

Answer (score 0):

FYI...don't assume that all focus changes will come via keyboard and mouse events, because assistive technologies like screen readers can set the focus to any focusable element. As such, consider enhancing @LeeBailey's suggestion with something like this:

```
$('#s1').cycle({ 
    fx:     'slideY', 
    speed:  300, 
    next:   '#s1', 
    timeout: 0,
    after: function (curr, next) {
        $(next).attr('aria-selected','true');
        $(curr).attr('aria-selected','false');
    }
});
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/gy8p5ewv/2/

Notice that, by default, I am adding the [aria-selected attribute](http://oaa-accessibility.org/examples/state/153/) to each element in your slider.

Hope this helps.